# How to launch an external application in Delphi and get the window handle of the newly started app?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get another application's window handle passed to Delphi via a mouse click.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608502/how-do-i-get-another-applications-window-handle-passed-to-delphi-via-a-mouse-cli)

Ok, I have been strugling with different ways to get the window handle of an external application passed to delphi. Is there a way that will allow me to for example to open a text file with notepad from within my delphi app (see code I used)

```
    procedure TfrmTestTrans.btnOpenFileClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  handleStartedApp := ShellExecute(frmTestTrans.Handle, nil, 'c:\windows\notepad.exe',
                        'c:\test.txt', nil, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
end;
```

But this doesn't give me an usable handle to the test.txt notepad window thats opened. I need to start an app and get the correct window handle to that app to enable my delphi program to do stuff with it.